# Prove that the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ of $\frac{x}{x-1} = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, epsilon-delta

> Prove that the limit as $x \rightarrow 0$ of $\frac{x}{x-1} = 0$.

I'm thinking of putting it in this form $|x| \lt \epsilon|x-1|$ and bounding it somehow, but I'm really at a loss of how to continue.  I tried letting $|x| \lt 1$ and then $-2 \lt x -1 \lt 0$ but I'm not sure how to continue as minimizing the right hand side would result in a $0$.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Around $x=0$ you can bound $|x-1|$, for instance if $|x|<1$, then $0<|x-1|=1-x<2$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien well it is preferable to have the reversed inequality $|x-1|>something$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $|x-1|>1/2$, e.g.

$-1/2 <x<1/2;$ or $|x|<1/2$.

Let $\epsilon$ be given.

Choose $\delta =\min (1/2, \epsilon/2);$

Then

$|x|<\delta$ implies

$|\frac{x}{x-1}| =|x|\frac{1}{|x-1|}<|x|\frac{1}{(1/2)}= $

$2|x| <2\delta \le 2(\epsilon/2)=\epsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

Take a sufficiently small neighborhood of $0$, say $[-\frac12,\frac12]$ and you have $|x-1|\le\frac32$, and this is true for any smaller neighborhood. This ensures

$$|x|<\epsilon|x-1|\le\frac{3\epsilon}2.$$

Comment: this is confusing, inequality get reversed between your first and second line.

Comment: @zwim: you are quite right. I have fixed.

Comment: I'm even more puzzled now... You are using $|x|<\epsilon|x-1|$ as a premise while this is what we want to prove. We don't need $|x|<k\epsilon$ since by hypothesis $x\to 0$. Also $|x-1|>\frac 12$ was good, it allows $\frac{|x|}{|x-1|}<2\epsilon$ as needed. Maybe it is the sentence by OP *"putting it in this form"* that brings confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply the facts that the limit of a sum is the sum of limits if they exist, that the limit of a constant is the same constant and that the limit of a ratio $f(x)/g(x)$ is the ratio of the limits, given that they exist and the limit of $g(x)$ isn't $0$ (which is true for $g(x) = x-1$ as $x\to 0$).

Comment: While this is correct, the OP wants to do a rigorous epsilon-delta proof using the definition of a limit.